# Header and Footer wont show up (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, header, uicollectionview, footer

~New to Swift~

Below is the func I have to implement header and footer views into my UICollectionView but as of now when I run my app nothing is showing up.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch  kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
      let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", forIndexPath: indexPath) 
      headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
      return headerView
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:
      let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", forIndexPath: indexPath)
      footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
      return footerView
    default:
      assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
 }
```